# Save byte array to Riak in Scala

Tags: scala, riak

I try to save file to riak storage. Here is simplified code for my problem

```
val bytes: Array[Byte] = "bbb".toCharArray.map(_.toByte)
val client: RiakClient = RiakClient(host, port)
Await.ready(client.ping, Duration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
val bucket: RiakBucket = client.bucket("fileStorage")
Await.ready(bucket.store("aaa",bytes), Duration.Inf)
```

I got next error

```
Error:(23, 29) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.scalapenos.riak.RiakMarshaller[Array[Byte]]
Await.ready(bucket.store("aaa",bytes), Duration.Inf)
```

I understand that I need to specify type in `bucket.store[X]("aaa",bytes)` but didn't found suitable type which I must put in place of `X`.

Is there the type I need in `Riak` library or should I implement it myself?

PS: I use this library from maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scalapenos</groupId>
    <artifactId>riak-scala-client_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find solution to my problem. So I changed library to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.basho.riak</groupId>
        <artifactId>riak-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and then

```
val location = new Location(namespace, key)
val storeValue = new RiakObject()
storeValue.setValue(BinaryValue.create(data.bytes))
val command = new StoreValue.Builder(storeValue)
  .withLocation(location)
  .build()
client.execute(command)
```

where `namespace` have type `Namespace`, `key` is `String` and `data.bytes` is `Array[Byte]`